# Changing Clustered Column Parameters in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a quick question about how to rearrange a clustered column chart in Excel for Mac 2011.  Here are the links to my data and chart:

Data:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9g5e.png]

Chart:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT5Bt.png]

I want to switch the years with the descriptions.  For instance, there would be three columns (Urban, Natural, Water) in the 1999 area, three in the 2000 area, etc.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel for Windows there is a button on the Chart ribbon to "Switch Rows/Columns". I don't have a Mac but would be very surprised if such a button was missing.

Edit: found this screenshot with the button in the dialog where the data source is selected.
[image]

And an article [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-make-an-excel-chart-in-office-2011-for-mac.html) showing a "Switch Plot" section on the ribbon.

[image]